# No database selected. MySQL Query Browser

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1046

I am using MySQL Query Browser 1.2.17. My problem is that using EXACTLY the same query sometimes I get `No database selected` error.

I tried to find any dependence in using `USE database;` or `FROM database.table`.

I have no idea when will I get an error and when I won't and if I get I don't know how to solve this (since there is in the query `USE database;`).

*UPDATE AND SOLUTION:*
Since the problem was independent neither on the `USE database;` nor `FROM database.table` and has been observed **RANDOMLY** (ex. run query, it works, then immediately run again with the same query and it didn't work anymore), I recreated the database simply filling it with data from backup and it helped.

Comment: What's the query?

Answer (score 2):

Best practice to write query.

> databasename.tablename

**example**

```
SELECT * FROM database.table where 1 = 1
```